# How to call a function with data passed in later

Tags: python

I am working on a school project where I calculate different predictors for some data and I created a function with some predictors so I can use them in a for cycle.

```
predictor_day = (
        [(f"Median {x}", create_median_predictor(x)) for x in (10, 30, 60, 80, 120)]
        + [(f"Average {x}", create_average_predictor(x)) for x in (10, 30, 60, 80, 120)]
        + [
            (f"Weighted average {x}", create_weighted_average_predictor(x))
            for x in (10, 30, 60, 80, 120)
        ]
    )
```

This is what one of the predictor functions looks like:

```
def create_median_predictor(window_size):
    def median_predictor(train_data):
        return median(train_data[-window_size:])

    return median_predictor
```

Now I also wanted to create a predictor, which takes all the data and returns a median of it, this is what it looks like:

```
def all_data_median_predictor(train_data):
    return median(train_data)
```

and this is where I am calling it:

```
for predictor in predictor_day:
       prediction = predictor(train_data)
```

but I cant seem to figure out a way how to add this one to my predictors_day variable, as it is allways missing parameter train_data, is there any way how I can add it to this variable?

Comment: What do you expect the for loop to do? Changing `prediction` within the loop will have no effect on `predictor_day`, just in case that's what you are trying to observe.

Comment: I am saving the prediction later on in the loop and comparing the mean absolute error, I just did not paste the whole for loop as to make it easier to read, the only thing I have a problem with is correctly adding `all_data_median_predictor` to my variable of predictors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the other lists, I assume the the type of `predictor_day` is `List[Tuple[str, Callable]]` .

```py
predictor_day = (
        [(f"Median {x}", create_median_predictor(x)) for x in (10, 30, 60, 80, 120)]
        + [(f"Average {x}", create_average_predictor(x)) for x in (10, 30, 60, 80, 120)]
        + [
            (f"Weighted average {x}", create_weighted_average_predictor(x))
            for x in (10, 30, 60, 80, 120)
        ]
        + [("all data median predictor", all_data_median_predictor)] # the change is in this line
    )
```

Comment: wow that was much simpler than I imagined it to be. I tried this with empty parenthesis, so that must be where I was getting error, thank you very much!